# What happens to unused views in UINavigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am implementing a shopping cart in iOS.

I am using a UINavigationController to show UIViewControllers for each step of the process. Users can use the back button and change things.

But after they submit the order I don’t want them to go back. What is the correct way to show a view without the back button using the navigation controller?

When you do that, what happen to the previous UIViewControllers? Are they deallocated ? Obviously I don’t need them. Do I have to manually deallocate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deallocate those view controllers. They will start to leak, otherwise. I guess, you would be pushing the view controllers somehow similar to the following.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
[myViewController release];
```

If you are doing like this, you have no need to worry about those view controllers, later. They will be released by the UINavigationController when it is done them.

**Hiding the back button:** Add the following line in the `loadView` method of your last view controller.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Comment: Yes I am pushing the views that way
How do I load the last view without the back button?

Comment: In the `loadView` method your last view controller, set `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES]`

Comment: @Simon - one quick point. iOS has no Garbage Collection. The UINavigationController retains the view when you pass it to the the said UINavigationController. This is reference counting, not garbage collecting. Otherwise, nice answer.

Comment: @Moshe: Yes.. You are correct about the garbage collection.. I was wrong there.. Thanks man..

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to go to a specific view controller either with something like:

```
[myNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or, there's also a UINavigationController method to give it an array of view controllers, it should present the first one.